# Boolean Operations on Non Boolean variables

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

```py
a = 5
b = -1
c = 2

print((c) and (b<0) and (a>0))
```

The output of the following code is `True`. But what is meant by `(c) and (b<0)`  ain't `and` and `or` used for Boolean type variables that `c` is a integer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In languages like C, there is no Boolean type or values; rather, integers are used in their place. Zero is false, all other integers are true.

Python generalizes this to *all* values. True, there is a Boolean type, but it's a subclass of `int`, and `True` and `False` are *literally* the values `1` and `0`, respectively. Any value can be *converted* to a Boolean value by calling `bool` on it.

```
>>> bool(5)
True
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool("foo"), bool([1,2,3])
True, True
>>> bool(""), bool([])
False, False
```

The "truthiness" of a value depends on its type, but roughly speaking, zeros and empty container-like values are False, and all other values are True. Further, `and` and `or` don't necessarily return a Boolean value:

```
x and y == y if bool(x) else x
x or y == x if bool(x) else y
```

`bool` is used to determine if `x` is true or not, but the result is one of the two actual values `x` or `y`.

Using the equivalence for `and`, we can evaluate your expression as

```
c and b<0 and a>0 == (b < 0 if bool(c) else c) and a > 0
                  == b < 0 if bool(2) else c) and a > 0
                  == (b < 0 if True else c) and a > 0
                  == b < 0 and a > 0
                  == a > 0 if bool(b < 0) else b < 0
                  == a > 0 if bool(-1 < 0) else b < 0
                  == a > 0 if bool(True) else b < 0
                  == a > 0 if True else b < 0
                  == a > 0
                  == 5 > 0
                  == True
```

I didn't substitute the values for `a`, `b`, and `c` all at once because `and`, `or`, and the conditional expression are all *lazy*; they don't evaluate an operand unless it's absolutely necessary, as we'll see in a moment.

If you change `c = 0`, the evaluation process produces the value of `c`, not the Boolean value of `c`. Note that we need to look at the value of `a`, because `a > 0` is never evaluated.

```
c and b<0 and a>0 == (b < 0 if bool(c) else c) and a > 0
                  == (b < 0 if bool(0) else c) and a > 0
                  == (b < 0 if False else c) and a > 0
                  == c and a > 0
                  == a > 0 if bool(c) else c
                  == a > 0 if bool(0) else c
                  == a > 0 if False else c
                  == c
                  == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, any object can be tested for a truth value. In the case of numeric types, any non-zero value is considered true. You can see the truth values of different types [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html).

Answer (score 1):

When a variable is not a bool and you check if it's `True` or `False`, python check if this variable is None or not.

For exemple:

```py
    a = 'any_value'
    print(a == True)
```

This statement prints `True`.

But:

```py
    b = None
    print(a == True)
```

Results in `False`.

Comment: In fact Python does more than just checking if it's None or not, see [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth).

Comment: Nice, didn't know this! Thanks!